# Why readPreference=secondaryPreferred is set then cannot connect to DB if primary down?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My NodeJS app is working with ReplicaSet of mongo. I want to client read data from secondary, so I set readPreference=secondary, but If secondary is down, NodeJS app cannot read data from mongo. With option secondaryPreferred, if no secondary is available, NodeJS can read data from primary instance. But if have no primary available, have only secondary available, I cannot start NodeJS app. It throw error `failed to connect to server [xxxx] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xx.xx.xx:27017`

How I can config mix between `secondary` and `secondaryPreferred`. I expect my NodeJS can start even have only one instance available, no care it's primary or secondary.  When NodeJS running, if have one mongo instance down, it's auto read from other instance

Comment: What is the configuration of your replicaset? How are you connecting to the cluster?

Comment: @prasad_ 1 primary, 1 secondary in members. I use mongoose to connect. mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxx:27017,xxx:27018/db?replicaSet=rs1&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&maxStalenessSeconds=120')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"if have no primary available" is not normal state of the replica. Let the election to happen, then start your app.

Primary is a mandatory member of a replica set. All writes are going to primary. When you **connect** to the replica-set the driver should know where to write to, even if you don't intend to write on application level.

Once connected, your application can survive temporary loss of primary and read from secondaries.

As a side note - consider [adding an arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-three-members/#primary-with-a-secondary-and-an-arbiter--psa-). 2 nodes replica set is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks, I just surprise that the replica set without primary, the driver can still connect to mongo with readPreference=secomdary, that why I consider about case replica set have no primary available.